# Neo4j Relationship Schema Indexes

Tags: neo4j, graph-databases, spring-data-neo4j

Using Neo4j 2.1.4 and SDN 3.2.0.RELEASE

I have a graph that connects nodes with relationships that have a UUID associated with them.  External systems use the UUID as a means to identify the source and target of the relationship.  Within Spring Data Neo4j (SDN) we have a `@RelationshipEntity(type=”LINKED_TO”)` class with a `@StartNode`, `@EndNode` and a String `uuid` field.  The `uuid` field is `@Indexed` and the resulting schema definition in Neo4j shows up as

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ SCHEMA
==> Indexes
...
==>   ON :Link(uuid) ONLINE
...
```

However, running a cypher query against the data, e.g.

```
MATCH ()-[r:LINKED_TO]->() WHERE uuid=’XXXXXX’ RETURN r;
```

does a full scan of the database and takes a long time

If I try to use the index by running

```
MATCH ()-[r:LINKED_TO]->() USING INDEX r:Link(uuid) WHERE uuid=’XXXXXX’ RETURN r;
```

I get

```
SyntaxException: Type mismatch: expected Node but was Relationship.
```

As I understand it, Relationships are supposed to be **first class citizens** in Neo4j, but I can’t see how to utilize the index on the relationship to prevent the graph equivalent of a table scan on the database to locate the relationship.

I know there are posts like [How to use relationship index in Cypher](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871820/how-to-use-relationship-index-in-cypher) which ask similar things, but this Link **is** the relationship between the two nodes.  If I converted the Link to a Node, we would be creating a Node to represent a Relationship which seems wrong when we are working in a graph database - I'd end up with `()-[:xxx]->(:Link)-[:xxx]->()` to represent one relationship.  It would make the model messy purely due to the fact that the Link couldn't be represented as a relationship.

The `Link` has got a unique, shared key attached to it that I want to use.  The Schema output suggests that the index is there for that field - I just can't use it.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks,

Dave

Comment: I don't get it. Is your `uuid` a **node** property or a **relationship** property? According to your schema, you have an index on `:Link(uuid)`, where `Link` is a label which can only exist on **nodes**. But in your second query, you're putting the label next to a **relationship** (which also explains your SyntaxException).

Comment: The `uuid` is a **relationship** property. I think there is some confusion as adding an `@Indexed(unique=true) String uuid;` onto the `@RelationshipEntity(type="LINKED_TO") public class Link` results in SDN executing `create constraint on (n:Link) assert n.uuid is unique` which, as you say, is actually creating a constraint on a Node with label `Link` - hence why it doesn't work.  I think that's a bug in SDN - it shouldn't allow `@Indexed` on a `@RelationshipEntity`.  But there's still the whole question about how to index the property on the `Link` relationship.

Answer (score 1):

Schema indexes are only available for nodes. The only way to index relationships is using legacy indexes or autoindexes. Legacy indexes need to be used explicitly in the `START` clause:

```
START r=relationship:my_index_name(uuid=<myuuid>)
RETURN r
```

I'm not sure how this can be used in conjunction with SDN.

side note: requiring relationship index is almost always a indication of doing something wrong in your graph data model. Everything being a `thing` or having an identity in your domain should be a node. So if a relationship requires a uuid, maybe the relationship refers to a thing and therefore should be converted into a node having a inbound relationship to the previous start node and a outbound relationship to the previous end node.